# About the definition of homeomorphism. Mathematicians didn't define homeomorphism like this. Why?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces; let $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection. If both the function $f$ and the inverse function $$f^{-1}:Y\to X$$ are continuous, then $f$ is called a **homeomorphism**.

I know group isomorphism, and I want to define homeomorphism as follows:

> My definition:
> Let $(X,\mathcal{O_1})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{O_2})$ be topological spaces; let $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection.
> Let $f(O)\in\mathcal{O_2}$ for any $O\in\mathcal{O_1}$.
> Let $f:\mathcal{O_1}\ni O\mapsto f(O)\in\mathcal{O_2}$ be a bijection.
> Then $f$ is called a **homeomorphism**.

Why is this definition bad?

---

Let $f$ be a homeomorphism by my definition.

By my definition, $f:\mathcal{O_1}\ni O\mapsto f(O)\in\mathcal{O_2}$ is bijective.

Sicne $f$ is surjective, $f(X)=Y$.

$f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ holds.

Since $f:X\to Y$ is bijective, $f(O_1)\cap f(O_2)=f(O_1\cap O_2)$ holds for any $O_1,O_2\in\mathcal{O_1}$.

$f(\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}O_\lambda)=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f(O_\lambda)$ holds, where $O_\lambda\in\mathcal{O_1}$ for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$.

Comment: They are trivially equivalent. I don't see any reason to prefer your definition to the other one.

Comment: Your second definition of homeomorphism means that $f$ is a bijective open map between topological spaces. The equivalence only holds true if $f$ is additionally continuous. Then you have: A continuous bijection $f$ between topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{V})$ is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is open.

Comment: For example: Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ be the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ then the identity from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ into $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{V})$ is a bijection which sends open sets into open sets. But it is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Orb Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: There is a book about counterexamples in topology called: Counterexamples in Topology from J. Arthur Seebach Jr. und Lynn Arthur Steen. It gives a good overview of topological properties that do not follow from another.

Comment: @Orb Thank you very much for the information.